# Верстка меню

Tags: html, css

Есть меню, пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы логотип был на одном уровне с ссылкой. Сейчас оно выглядит так

[image]

Сам код

```
<div class="rub">
    <div class="rubimg">
        <img src="{THEME}/image/avto/audi.png" height="15" /><br />
        <img src="{THEME}/image/avto/ford.png" height="15" /><br />
        <img src="{THEME}/image/avto/audi.png" height="15" /><br />
        <img src="{THEME}/image/avto/bmw.png" height="15" /><br />
        <img src="{THEME}/image/avto/audi.png" height="15" /><br />
        <img src="{THEME}/image/avto/mazda.png" height="15" /><br />
        <img src="{THEME}/image/avto/audi.png" height="15" /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="rublink">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/sat/2/audi">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/sat/2/audi">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/sat/2/audi">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/sat/2/audi">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/sat/2/audi">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/sat/2/audi">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/sat/2/audi">Audi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

и css

```
.rub {
    background: url("../image/h_rub.jpg") no-repeat;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.rub ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.rub a {
    color: #565656;
    font-weight: bold;
    font: 18px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.rubimg {
    max-width:55px;
    float:left;
}

.rub img {
    max-width: 50px;
    height: 15px;
}

.rublink {
    margin-left:5px; 
    max-width:245px; 
    float:left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: А `padding` не работает??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать добавить line-height

```
.rublink li{
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

А вообще я бы поменял разметку.

**UPD**
.rublink a{
    padding-left: 30px;
}

Comment: Если разметку можно поменять, то вот так должно работать http://jsfiddle.net/invincible/bWCAF/

Comment: Так то да, но тогда ссылки не друг под другом расположены получаются, с этим и проблема.

Comment: Как не друг под другом, они все одна под другой? Сформулируйте вопрос точнее, что Вам нужно?

Comment: Не друг под другом потому что ширина картинок разная. Вот так это выглядит http://i009.radikal.ru/1205/f4/2e1527f2ae62.png

Comment: Тю, ну сразу так и нужно было нарисовать. padding-left юзайте. Смотрите UPD к ответу.

Comment: А если Li позиционировать от прового края а img от левого?

Comment: Пробовал :) В таком случае ссылка двигается от картинки, они разной ширины, вот и выходит что получается тоже самое)

Comment: Вот как нужно http://jsfiddle.net/invincible/bWCAF/1/ 
Не сразу вопрос понял. Я раньше такое делал по другому, к элементам списка картинки цеплял через background и тогда padding нормально работает.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется что лучше в один див засунуть картинку и ссылку соответствующюю ей этому диву задать `margin` и такие дивы поместить в контейнер и кода станет меньше и функциональность станет понятней и кросбрузерность гарантирована...

***UPD***
 А если верстку поменять незьзя то и картинкам и ссылкам задать `display: block;` и одинаковые `margin`

Comment: Я так делал изначально, но в таком случае проблема выровнять ссылки, чтобы анкоры ссылки начинались были один под другим

Comment: А если использовать UPD моего ответа?

Comment: Попробовал сейчас, не выходит, все остается почти также

Answer (score 0):

Я вообще не могу уловить суть в твоей верстки. лучше всего делать концепцию<br/>
`<ul>
 <li><img /><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>`
ну и задавать стили
если нельзя то li полнустью обнулять так же как и ul и уже li задавать display: block